# Does gdb support comments in the command line (gdb prompt)?

Tags: gdb

I want to comment `gdb` commands in the command prompt at the end of the line for two use cases:

1. Writing a tutorial
2. Documenting a `gdb` command file for automatic execution

While `gdb` command files seem to [support comments via the hash (`#`) symbol](http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_toc.html#TOC143)
I cannot find any command marker for the `gdb` command line:

```
(gdb) print 1
$2 = 1
(gdb) print 1   // comment
A syntax error in expression, near `/ comment'.
(gdb) print 1   -- comment
A syntax error in expression, near `comment'.
(gdb) print 1   # comment
Invalid character '#' in expression.
(gdb) print 1   ; comment
Invalid character ';' in expression.
(gdb) print 1   /* comment */
No symbol "comment" in current context.
```

How can I append comments?

**Edit:** According to the [`gdb` documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Syntax.html#Command-Syntax)

> Any text from a # to the end of the line is a comment;
> it does nothing.
> This is useful mainly in command files

I am not sure why it doesn't work as documented...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use it on its own line, but not at the end of a line. E.g.:

```
(gdb) # foo
(gdb) print "foo"
$1 = "foo"
```

Comment: Thanks for proving this. My use case is to minimize the number of rows  in a tutorial script (this is the reason for asking for comments at the end of the line) so this would be a fall-back only if nothing better is possible